# SQL output formatted in one line per entry

Tags: sql, oracle, format, output

I have a problem getting data displayed right, directly from Oracle SQL.

I have 2 tables. Medarb with entries meda_id and init and contacts with meda_id, cont_type and number.

The cont_type can be either 'MT' or 'MA'

what I get is:

```
init  type number
aaaa  MT   11111111
aaaa  MA   22222222
bbbb  MT   33333333
bbbb  MA   44444444 and so on.
```

what I wanted was: (each person on one line)

```
aaaa mt 11111111 ma 22222222
bbbb mt 33333333 ma 44444444 and so on.
```

Is that possible?

The SQL is like this:

```
select distinct medarb.init, contacts.cont_type, contacts.number
from contacts
inner join medarb on medarb.meda_id = contacts.meda_id
order by medarb.init
```

Kind regards
Per

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation usually helps in such situations.

```
SQL> with test (init, type, cnumber) as
  2    (select 'aaaa', 'MT', 111 from dual union all
  3     select 'aaaa', 'MA', 222 from dual union all
  4     select 'bbbb', 'MT', 333 from dual union all
  5     select 'bbbb', 'MA', 444 from dual
  6    )
  7  select init,
  8    'MT' mttype,
  9    max(case when type = 'MT' then cnumber end) cnum_mt,
 10    'MA' matype,
 11    max(case when type = 'MA' then cnumber end) cnum_ma
 12  from test
 13  group by init
 14  order by init;

INIT MT    CNUM_MT MA    CNUM_MA
---- -- ---------- -- ----------
aaaa MT        111 MA        222
bbbb MT        333 MA        444

SQL>
```

Comment: do you have to write each line like the 2-5? there is 5000+ entries so would defeat the purpose. And I cant figure out where you would want to put the 2 tables I request data from: medarb and contacts

Comment: No, it is just sample data (the one you posted). Query you should be looking at begins at line #7.

Comment: but you select form "test" in line 7-12 so you would have to have the data there to select from, If I get it right I need to have my original select in the first part. right? so select from tables medarb and contacts and not from dual, (the 4 lines of output, is as said part of 5000+ output)

Comment: If you provided test case (which includes CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data), I'd be able to post a query which is related to that. As you chose not to, I created my own test case and showed you **how** to do that - use aggregation. Now you should apply it (aggregation) to your situation.

Comment: the tables allrdy exits in the database, and the data I post was a small part that the existing sql query gave. 

but with your example, I was able to figure out what I was missing. So thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

what is the unique column combination for this join, is it init and type columns?
You can try using Oracle Pivot functions.

https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot

thanks

Comment: I'll check it out, and the unique colum is the medarb_meda_id which can be found in both medarb and contacts